# On iphone, safari, when typing in an input, the screen goes white

Tags: ios, iphone, wordpress, input, safari

I've tested this on every other browser, it's only on iphone on safari where this is happening.  I've built a site on wordpress and whenever a comment field is clicked on a comment, the screen goes white briefly.  Cna someone point me in the right direction on how to diagnose this? Thanks!

http://texas-coffee-school.steadfastlight.com/is-inconsistency-killing-your-coffee-business-from-within/#comments  To see.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer: By applying position: relative on all the form objects, this fixes the issue iOS was having with the form fields.

Comment: Just had the same problem and `position: relative` helped, thanks!

Comment: This did not work for me. But I found that removing `overflow: auto` on the form's parent container, stopped the white screen issue when clicking into the field.

Answer (score -1):

Try pressing F12 on Google Chrome for developer tools and emulate the device (by clicking the phone icon and selecting the device required) that is causing the problems (e.g. Apple iPhone6), run the console while leaving a comment and it should display whatever Javascript is running in the background and debug from there.

Comment: In terms of other debug options, try disabling your plugins one by one and see if any of these are causing the issue specifically. Also, consider switching themes temporarily to see if it is a theme specific issue.

Comment: when in Chrome's debug emulating the iphone, it won't replicate.